How to read files inside the project with QFile
I follow these simple steps to recreate the problem. Create a new Qt project in Qt Creator, a widget. Create a new widget class "newform" with its .cpp, .h, and .ui files. Try to load it on a QFile (see below) and verify if it can be opened with an if and end the code if it does not load it correctly. This would be the code of the constructor of the main class (mainwindow.cpp):
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    QFile file(":/newform.ui");
    if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
        qWarning("Failed to load UI file!");
        return;
    }
}

This somehow does not load the .ui file and always trigger that warning message.
In the project, it is loaded to be loaded with QUiLoader later, but I cannot even load it since I always get that "Failed to load Ui file!" message when running. Why? What is wrong here?
The file newform.ui is not on included in a .qrc file, it's just a file in the same folder as mainwindow.ui. Do I have to use a Qt Resource File (qrc)?

That is because all resources must be loaded from a Qt Resource File (.qrc). Create a qrc file, add a prefix (let's call it rsc), add the corresponding .ui file. Then just load it like this:
QFile file(":/rsc/newform.ui"); //adding the prefix

